# My JUnit tests executes with maven build in Java 11, but unable to run same Junit tests via RunIT->Run As->Units, which always says not JUnits found

Tags: eclipse, junit4, java-11

My module test project is supposed to be built using Java 11 as it is referencing to a jar which is build in Java 11. Hence I had to compile my code in Java 11. **When I do Maven clean install, my JUnit test cases are executed without any issue.** *But when I tried to run my test cases via RunIT->Run As-> JUnit tests, it says "no JUnit tests found"*

- When I first set up this project, I was able to run via RunIT->Run As-> JUnit tests, which worked absolutely fine. But I had another module in my workspace, which was working on Java 1.8. After testing the tests in that module and coming back to my test project, this stopped working.
- When I set compiler to Java 1.8, my tests are identified
- Following are the configurations I have tried with

  - I am working on Eclipse Java 2019-03, which supports Java 11
  - I have set Preferences-> java -> Compiler -> Compiler compliance level to 11, and Installed JREs point to Java 11.
  - Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> set to Java 11
  - Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler -> set to Java 11
  - In my module pom, I am referencing to JUnit 4
  - While executing RunIT-> Run As -> Run Configurations, I have selected Java 11 JRE.
  - I have done maven clean install, and all the test-classes are present in the expected target folder. I have Maven-> clean, deletes the target folder.
  - After building my project via Maven, I have done "Maven Update" as well.
- In my module pom file, I have set compiler version

```py
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
        <source>11</source>
        <target>11</target>
        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
        <testSource>11</testSource>
        <testTarget>11</testTarget>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue [with Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12)](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades)? Maybe you are facing an already fixed bug. Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11) is one release behind. Please show also your JUnit dependency of your `pom.xml`.

Comment: For the Run Configuration, have your tried a Java 11 JDK instead of a JRE? And are you sure you are using the JUnit 4 Runner as well (I think it defaults to 5, now)?

Comment: @howlger, here is my JUnit dependancy in my POM.xml
 <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

Comment: @nitind, yes I have configured Java 11 JDK only. POM config for JUnit 4 is shown in my above comment.

Comment: @DivyaJ Your Eclipse IDE is outdated. Please upgrade. Let's not waste time on retrocomputing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got solved by opening the Java 11 project in different workspace. Before that I ensure that JAVA_HOME is set with to JAVA 11 and then open the eclipse.